# Simplest way to clear a container using raphaeljs javascript graphical library

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael

I have to clear and redraw a raphael javascript main container. I've tried with

```
var paper = Raphael(10, 50, 320, 200);
paper.remove();  // Doesn't work
paper.node.removeNode();    //this neither
paper.removeNode();   //this neither
```

Any idea?

Comment: http://raphaeljs.com/, an graphical javascript library

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Actually it's just come to my notice that there's the much easier paper.clear(); It's not documented.

Comment: Yes now it's documented
http://dmitrybaranovskiy.github.io/raphael/reference.html#Paper.clear

Answer (score 15):

When you create a paper it creates a DOM object. You can access this with

```
paper.canvas
```

When you create a new Raphael object, you create a new DOM object and leave the original one alone! This is the best way to do it considering everything though. If you want to delete the canvas you only need to do the next command:

```
//Note: after calling this function the paper object will be useless!
//Make paper object null (or a new paper object) immediately!
function clearPaper(paper){
    var paperDom = paper.canvas;
    paperDom.parentNode.removeChild(paperDom);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

with the latest gRaphael 0.5.1, I clear the chart easily with just calling the clear() method.
i.e.

```
var r = Raphael(...)
r.clear();
```

But I'm not sure if it would work for your version

Answer (score 0):

Yes!
you have to plough to the end of the docs..

```
(
function (local_raphael) 
{
/*Put your little bit of Rap code in here*/ 
var paper = local_raphael(10, 10, 320, 200); 
}
)(Raphael.ninja());
```

http://www.irunmywebsite.com/raphael/raphaelsource.html

Comment: Raphael.ninja() (http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Raphael.ninja) removes the whole library, so I don't think it is possible to do anything else in Raphael after calling it. I think paper.clear() would be sufficient to remove the elements on the paper, or paper.remove() to actually remove the paper from the DOM.